# How to resolve Flask internal server error with AWS EB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment running Python 3.6. I am trying to run a Flask application in it but I keep getting a 500 internal server error when I click on the URL provided by Elastic Beanstalk:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Here is my basic file structure:

```
ProjectRoot/
    .ebextenstions/
        application.config
    .elasticbeanstalk/
        config.yml
    env
    myapp/
        static
        templates
        __init__.py
        routes.py
    .ebignore
    application.py
    requirements.txt
```

Here is my application.config file:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: application.py
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "application/static/"
```

I am hosting a PHP website using Elastic Beanstalk, but Flask seems to be much more complicated. I think that my issue is just a misconfiguration, but I have not yet found any solution.

Answer (score -2):

I do recommend that you debug your application using the verbose mode of Flask and SQLAlchemy, so you can better know whats going on, with this level of detail I can only suggest something to check like the permissions/IAM on AWS, to check if your ElasticBeanstalk can really access the RDS, I'm assuming the ELB/applcation use a set of credentials, and you tested locally with another credential, right?

About the "verbose mode", try setting the SQLALCHEMY_ECHO to True: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/ There's also this option ive not tested: https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/208/files?short_path=fd40cf2

And on the Flask app you can set debug to True also.

Another option, is to debug if you can connect on the RDS directly with a client on the machine/container, or a least if a telnet is working.

Comment: when explaining please at least give a one example.